# sample data not loading in 0.74.0-beta10

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, sample-data

I'm having no luck getting the sample data to load in the current rev., and I've had no trouble at all in previous versions. My composer.json contains the following, edited for brevity:

> {
>     "name": "magento/magento2ce",
>      "description": "Magento 2 (Community Edition)",
>      "type": "project",
>      "version": "0.74.0-beta10",
>      "license": [
>          "OSL-3.0",
>          "AFL-3.0"

and ...

> "magento/sample-bundle-all": "1.0.0",
>           "magento/sample-data": "0.74.0-beta9"

and at the end of the file:

> "minimum-stability": "beta",
>       "prefer-stable": true,
>       "repositories": {
>           "magento": {
>               "type": "composer",
>               "url": "http://packages.magento.com"
>           }
>       }
>   }

Here's what's happening. The sample-bundle-all downloads and installs correctly. The sample-data does not download the main file, but ONLY downloads the required files in sample-data-media and sample-data-fixtures.

First time through the web installer interface, the sample modules install, but the sample data box is greyed out.

I checked the vendor/magento directory to see what packages it contained for install and it lists the following:

magento-composer-installer
sample-data-fixtures
sample-data-media
sample-module-interception
sample-module-minimal
sample-module-modifycontents
sample-module-newpage
sample-module-service-contract-client
sample-module-service-contract-replacement
sample-module-theme
sample-module-webapi-client
sample-module-webflow
zendframework1

I admit I am at a loss to figure this out.

I have tried clearing the composer cache with clearcache. I have tried installing the sample-data both with the initial install, and having that fail, again as a separate install later. Neither works.

I get one of two errors or outcomes, I either get a 'nothing to update or install' message from composer when I try to install AFTER the initial install. I ran composer update on the base directory.

The other error is various text telling me that there is no such file in the magento repository, which I find dubious at best.

I'm baffled and any advice and counsel is gratefully welcomed.

Last point, I did use the 'uninstall magento' prior to upgrading, so the database was dropped and reloaded by the uninstall/install process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look what I did for beta10 (I guess they didn't had the sample-data in pcackage beta 10 yet, but beta9 package works with beta10)

I did this and it worked (I don't know if it's a bug ot not but I had nothing in the Men Categories, and lot of products in Women etc) :

composer.json : add :

```
"require-dev": {
    "magento/sample-data": "~0.74.0-beta9",
```

Add this only if you also want app/code/MagentoSample*** modules (other thing than sample-data):

```
    "magento/sample-bundle-all": "*",
```

Then run

```
    composer update

    php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

You shall see a very long data loading

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this. See http://bit.ly/1HSALaY

Instead of using the dev/tools script, you can use a bin/magento sampledata:install  script. Be sure to run bin/magento setup:upgrade first because sample data is now a module. The setup:upgrade commands enables the module in config.php